# Why I got Blank Json Response in Jsp page?

Tags: java, json, ajax

**This is my json body what i got from my struts action class.**

```
{"responseDetailsList":[{"responseId":122,"dataSource":"BJ","status":"D","organizationId":573,"organizationName":"PREMIER ALLOYS \u0026 CHEMICALS P LTD","supplierMasterStatus":0,"categoryTaggingStatus":0,"mmrInfo":{"tenderDownloadStatus":0,"mmrCreationStatus":0,"mmResponseStatusCode":"NA","mmResponseStatus":"NOT_FOUND"},"rarInfo":{"contactPersonId":619,"contactPersonName":"RAVI MARDA ","emailId":"a@a.a","phoneNo":"999999999","auctionId":0,"participationStatus":[{"ruleId":110,"ruleCode":"MULTI_BID_SEALED_BID","ruleTypeCode":"SB"}]}},{"responseId":123,"dataSource":"BJ","status":"D","organizationId":574,"organizationName":"Essel Mining \u0026 Industries Ltd.","supplierMasterStatus":0,"categoryTaggingStatus":0,"mmrInfo":{"tenderDownloadStatus":0,"mmrCreationStatus":0,"mmResponseStatusCode":"NA","mmResponseStatus":"NOT_FOUND"},"rarInfo":{"contactPersonId":620,"contactPersonName":"Divyang Dhonde ","emailId":"a@a.a","phoneNo":"999999999","auctionId":0,"participationStatus":[{"ruleId":110,"ruleCode":"MULTI_BID_SEALED_BID","ruleTypeCode":"SB"}]}},{"responseId":124,"dataSource":"BJ","status":"D","organizationId":2117,"organizationName":"MAMTA SURGICAL \u0026 COTTON","supplierMasterStatus":0,"categoryTaggingStatus":0,"mmrInfo":{"tenderDownloadStatus":0,"mmrCreationStatus":0,"mmResponseStatusCode":"NA","mmResponseStatus":"NOT_FOUND"},"rarInfo":{"contactPersonId":2163,"contactPersonName":"Sanjay Rathi ","emailId":"debosmita.dutta@mjunction.in","phoneNo":"999999999","auctionId":0,"participationStatus":[{"ruleId":110,"ruleCode":"MULTI_BID_SEALED_BID","ruleTypeCode":"SB"}]}}],"categoryId":107,"requestId":419897}
```

### Below is my action class

```
int requestIdForJson = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("requestId"));
                int categoryIdForJson = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("categoryId"));

                MMRResponse mmrResponse = sdaService.getMMRResponseDetails(requestIdForJson, categoryIdForJson, userId);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String jsonStr = gson.toJson(mmrResponse);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.getWriter().print(jsonStr);
                System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

This is my ajax call where i print the response but i am getting blank response.

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url : crcEncodeUrl("/EPSWeb/sda/getResponseAddAction.do?operation=load&requestId="+$('#requestId').val()+"&categoryId="+$('#categoryId').val()),
                        contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                        dataType : "html",                  
                        success : function(responseJson) {
                            //var jsonObject = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                            alert(responseJson);
                            console.log("abc");
                        }                       
                    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on server console?

Comment: no but i am getting blank html response.

Comment: Your success function is running?In alert you are getting blank JSON? If it is not running add error function and check what you are getting in error function

Comment: my success function is running and in alert i am getting blank json.

Comment: what is type of response object is it of type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse?

Comment: Try to add return null; last line of your function